# What is the best way to create breadcrumbs based on a structure?

Tags: navigation, structure

How do you create breadcrumbs based on a structure?

**My structure:**

- Parent

  - Child (active)
  - Other Child

Child

**My url:**

site.com/parent/child

**So my breadcrumb need to be:**

home (url) / parent (url) / child

Comment: The official method is described in this Craft support doc: https://craftcms.com/support/breadcrumbs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it!

```
{% if craft.request.segments %}
<nav class="breadcrubs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
                {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
                    <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```