# Breadcrumbs for Craft 3

Tags: templating, craft3

How do you make breadcrumbs in your Twig templates for Craft 3?

Unfortunately I found examples only for Craft 2

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to creating breadcrumbs, I can only offer advice when doing so within a structure.

Craft 3 still has `.ancestors` available on an entry so you can do:

```
{% set breadcrumbs = entry.ancestors.all() %}
```

Then check the length and loop through the ancestors for the structure entry.

```
{% if breadcrumbs|length %}
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
        {% for crumb in breadcrumbs %}
            <li><a href="{{ crumb.url }}">{{ crumb.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Then just add a little CSS to style as you choose.

```
<style>
  .breadcrumbs {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .breadcrumbs li { display: inline; }
  .breadcrumbs li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "\000BB";
  }
</style>
```

This would use `&raquo;` between each entry.

Home » First Article » Another Article » Grandchild Article

Comment: What is the `default([])` good for? The default return value from `all` is an empty array. Could you please explain the sense of that filter?

Comment: That’s a great point @RobinSchambach. I think I just had that left in there as a precautionary measure in an older project but I’ve edited it out of my answer since it is superfluous and could just bring confusion.

Comment: This is a good solution for the structure. But if we use singles, channels, this solution does not work. And it seems there is no universal solution, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I'm using. It traverses the url segments and loads the associated entry to build the breadcrumb (using Bootstrap 4.x) - Not sure this is the most efficient/correct way, but hopefully this helps someone:

```
{% if craft.request.segments %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
                {% for segment in craft.request.segments %}
                {% set segmentEntries = craft.entries.slug(segment).find() %}
                {% for segmentEntry in segmentEntries %}
                    {% if segmentEntry.id == entry.id %}
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">{{ segmentEntry.title }}</li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ segmentEntry.url }}">{{ segmentEntry.title }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
              </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Built using code from this thread as inspiration: [What is the best way to create breadcrumbs based on a structure?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-breadcrumbs-based-on-a-structure)

Answer (score 1):

The verbb navigation plugin has a good breadcrumbs service:

https://github.com/verbb/navigation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the breadcrumb template component for Craft CMS 3. It is automatically created from URL structure.

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/breadcrumb-created-from-url-for-craft-cms

- It creates proper links for entries, categories and any other elements that have their own page.
- It works out of the box. No need to adjust anything unless you are dealing with custom routes instead of regular entries and categories.
- It has proper google structured data and ARIA attributes.